# Unsupervised classification in QGIS with Orfeo toolbox

Tags: qgis, r, clustering, orfeo-toolbox

I want to run an unsupervised classification of two landsat images in QGIS. Therefor I want to compute a k-means and a SOM (self organizing maps) classification. Unfortunately it doesn't work.

I tried to reinstall and install the new QGIS version (2.10) - and looked for Orfeo Toolbox Updates but unfortunately I couldn't run it (nor with different input data). Here is the logfile of the process in QGIS 2.10 (Windows 7)

```
 Algorithmus Unsupervised KMeans image classification startet...
C:\OSGeo4W\bin\otbcli_KMeansClassification
-in
"C:/Users/Manu/Documents/MASTERARBEIT/RemoteSensing_LandsatCDR/2010186_band4_BoaRef.tif"
-ram
128
-ts
100
-nc
5
-maxit
1000
-ct
0.0001
-out
"C:/Users/Manu/Documents/MASTERARBEIT/try/try.tif"
-outmeans
"C:/Users/Manu/Documents/MASTERARBEIT/try/try2"
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden. 
Converting outputs
Lade Ergebnis Layer
```

The system can't find the path it states in the 3rd line from the bottom. (Path obviously is correct - and if defined error message stays the same.)
Same with the SOM algorithm in the following logfile extract:

```
    Algorithmus SOM Classification startet...
C:\OSGeo4W\bin\otbcli_SOMClassification
-in
"C:/Users/Manu/Documents/MASTERARBEIT/try/merge2.tif"
-tp
1
-ts
0
-sl
0
-sx
32
-sy
32
-nx
10
-ny
10
-ni
5
-bi
1
-bf
0.1
-iv
0
-ram
128
-rand
0
-out
"C:\Users\Manu\AppData\Local\Temp\processing\9d88158a0c1d42aeaf0ffa70e4744d0d\out.tif"
-som
"C:\Users\Manu\AppData\Local\Temp\processing\8bb385e883cb44039abe7125bb2bbd35\som.tif"
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden. 
Converting outputs
Lade Ergebnis Layer
```

I suppose the toolbox doesn't work properly as I tried different input data, different QGIS versions, different output paths (from above are temporary; but I also tried to save the output directly on disc - ergo providing a path),...

Should I contact OrfeoToolbox directly?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that QGIS expects a specific install path for the Orfeo Toolbox.

"QGIS assumes that the “OTB applications folder” is located at /usr/lib/otb/applications"